# How to write a cursor in sql to compare two table data and finding fifocost from one by one record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to write a cursor to compare two tables data and find a fifo cost.

I have written this query for a cursor but it is not getting correct cost.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_GETFIFOCOST](@pid nvarchar(250)) 
as
Begin
  Declare @qty decimal(18,2),@cost decimal(18,2),@line int
  Declare @qty1 decimal(18,2),@cost1 decimal(18,2),@line1 int

  Declare MyCur Cursor for 
    select QTY_IN,UNIT_COST,LINE 
    from STOCKDETAILS  
    where STOCK_JR in ('IN','GR','TR','SA','OS','SR','AS','OG','PO') 
    and PRODUCT_NO=@pid order   by STOCK_DATE

  Declare @fqty decimal(18,2)

  Open MyCur

  Fetch next from mycur into @qty, @cost, @line

  While @@Fetch_Status=0
  Begin
    Declare MyCur1 Cursor for 
       select QTY_IN,UNIT_COST,LINE 
       from STOCKDETAILS  
       where STOCK_JR in ('OU','IS','SJ','TR','SA','CS','AS','PR','DO') 
         and PRODUCT_NO=@pid order by STOCK_DATE

    Open MyCur1
    Fetch next from mycur1 into @qty1, @cost1, @line1

    While @@Fetch_Status = 0
    Begin
        if @qty&gt;=@qty1 
           set @qty=@qty-@qty1
      set @fqty=@fqty+@qty
      if @qty&lt;@qty1 
        set @qty=@qty-@qty1
      set @fqty=@fqty+@qty-@qty1
      Fetch Next From MyCUr into @qty,@cost,@line
      Fetch Next From MyCUr1 into @qty1,@cost1,@line1
      while @fqty=0
      Begin
        update STOCKDETAILS 
        set FIFO_COST=@cost 
        where LINE=@line1
      End
    End
    Close Mycur
    Close Mycur1
    Deallocate Mycur
    Deallocate Mycur1
  End
End

Exec SP_GETFIFOCOST 'F1'
```

I have written same logic at the front end like this

```
b = table2.Rows.Count - 1;

try
{
    for (a = table1.Rows.Count - 1; a &gt;= 0; a--)
    {
        total();

        while (fqty != 0 &amp;&amp; fqty &gt;= 0)
        {
            if (b &gt;= 0)
            {
                b = b - 1;
                total();
            }
            else
            {
                fqty = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception EX) { }

void total()
{
    try
    {
        fout = Convert.ToDecimal(table2.Rows[b][&quot;QTY_OUT&quot;].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception EX) { fout = 0; }

    try
    {
        fin = Convert.ToDecimal(table1.Rows[a][&quot;QTY_IN&quot;].ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception EX) { fin = 0; }

    if (fin &gt;= fout)
    {
        fqty = fin - fout;
        table1.Rows[a][&quot;QTY_IN&quot;] = fqty;

        try
        {
            string fc = table1.Rows[a][&quot;UNIT_COST&quot;].ToString();
            string sn = table2.Rows[b][&quot;LINE&quot;].ToString();

            TRcmd.Connection = cn;
            TRcmd.CommandText = &quot;update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST='&quot; + fc + &quot;' where LINE='&quot; + sn + &quot;'&quot;;
            TRcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            TRcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception EX) { }

        if (fqty == 0)
        {
            b = b - 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fqty = 0;
        table1.Rows[a][&quot;QTY_IN&quot;] = fqty;

        try
        {
            string fc = table1.Rows[a][&quot;UNIT_COST&quot;].ToString();
            string sn = table2.Rows[b][&quot;LINE&quot;].ToString();

            TRcmd.Connection = cn;
            TRcmd.CommandText = &quot;update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST='&quot; + fc + &quot;' where LINE='&quot; + sn + &quot;'&quot;;
            TRcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            TRcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception EX) { }

        a = a - 1;

        try
        {
            table1.Rows[a][&quot;QTY_IN&quot;] = Convert.ToDecimal(table1.Rows[a][&quot;QTY_IN&quot;].ToString()) + (fin - fout);
        }
        catch (Exception EX) { }

        a = a + 1;
        b = b - 1;
    }
}
```

Would you please help me?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: That's K I will modify that would u pls post logic in cursor for finding FIFO Cost by checking every record in both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE [RISE_DB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_GETFIFOCOST]    Script Date: 09/15/2015 15:34:11 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_GETFIFOCOST](@pid nvarchar(250)) as
    Begin
    Declare @qty decimal(18,2),@cost decimal(18,2),@line int
    Declare @qty1 decimal(18,2),@cost1 decimal(18,2),@line1 int
    Declare @fqty decimal(18,2)
    set @fqty=0
    Declare MyCur1 Cursor for select QTY_OUT,UNIT_COST,LINE from STOCKDETAILS  where STOCK_JR in ('OU','IS','SJ','TR','SA','CS','AS','PR','DO') and PRODUCT_NO=@pid order by STOCK_DATE
    Open MyCur1
    Declare MyCur Cursor for select QTY_IN,UNIT_COST,LINE from STOCKDETAILS  where STOCK_JR in ('IN','GR','TR','SA','OS','SR','AS','OG','PO') and PRODUCT_NO=@pid order by STOCK_DATE
    Open MyCur
    if @fqty=0
    begin
    Fetch Next From MyCur1 into @qty1,@cost1,@line1
    Fetch Next From MyCur into @qty,@cost,@line
    End
    While @@Fetch_Status=0
    Begin
    While @@Fetch_Status=0
    Begin
    if @qty>@qty1
    begin
    set @qty=@qty-@qty1
    update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST=@cost where LINE=@line1
    set @fqty=@fqty+@qty
    if @fqty>0
    begin
    Fetch Next From MyCur1 into @qty1,@cost1,@line1
    set @fqty=@qty-@qty1
    update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST=@cost where LINE=@line1
    end
    end
    if @qty<@qty1
    begin
    set @fqty=@qty-@qty1
    update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST=@cost where LINE=@line1
    if @fqty<0
    begin
    Fetch Next From MyCur into @qty,@cost,@line
    Fetch Next From MyCur1 into @qty1,@cost1,@line1
    set @qty1=@fqty-@qty1
    set @fqty=@qty+@qty1
    if @fqty>0
    begin
    set @qty=@qty+@qty1
    end
    update STOCKDETAILS set FIFO_COST=@cost where LINE=@line1
    end
    end
    if @fqty=0
    begin
    Fetch Next From MyCur1 into @qty1,@cost1,@line1
    Fetch Next From MyCur into @qty,@cost,@line
    End
    End
    end
    Close MyCur1
    Close MyCur
    Deallocate MyCur1
    Deallocate MyCur
    End
```